# How to manage global state in swift apps and update UI when this state has changed?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm coming from `react-native` where you can write IOS apps using JavaScript. There's a module called `redux` (I believe many people know it) where you can store your app state and every single view controller (component) will get notified & updated if the state changes. I wonder what's the swift approach to achieve this?

Here are some scenarios that can help you understand my question:

1. A user changes his profile picture in the app, then every screen that displays the user's account info will get updated so that the new profile picture is displayed
2. Imagine an app for sharing articles. Each article has tags that represent the categories of it. Your app has a tab bar with each tab being a category like this:

[image]

There is an article whose tags include both "Pets" and "Family" and therefore, this article is displayed on both "Pets" and "Family" screens. A user presses the `heart` button of the article on "Pets" screen to like this article and switches to "Family" screen to see the exact same article. The `heart` button of the same article on "Family" screen should also be activated

I wonder how this can be done in swift?